# showing multiple input via check box in line plot (shiny)

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, line

Am creating a shiny app to show multiple companies stock price into a line plot for comparison. However, my app only runs right when I choose a single company. How do I add more lines on showing the different company data inside the plot?

Dummy data:

```
> dput(data_3[1:10,])
structure(list(date = structure(c(10959, 10960, 10961, 10962, 
10963, 10966, 10967, 10968, 10969, 10970), class = "Date"), code = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("AAPL", "AMZN", 
"BABA", "FB", "GOOG", "INTC", "MSFT", "SAP"), class = "factor"), 
    close_price = c(3.997768, 3.660714, 3.714286, 3.392857, 3.553571, 
    3.491071, 3.3125, 3.113839, 3.455357, 3.587054), volume = c(133949200, 
    128094400, 194580400, 191993200, 115183600, 126266000, 110387200, 
    244017200, 258171200, 97594000), company = structure(c(3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Alibaba", 
    "Amazon", "Apple", "Facebook", "Google", "Intel", "Microsoft", 
    "SAP"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")

> head(data_3)
        date code close_price    volume company
1 2000-01-03 AAPL    3.997768 133949200   Apple
2 2000-01-04 AAPL    3.660714 128094400   Apple
3 2000-01-05 AAPL    3.714286 194580400   Apple
4 2000-01-06 AAPL    3.392857 191993200   Apple
5 2000-01-07 AAPL    3.553571 115183600   Apple
6 2000-01-10 AAPL    3.491071 126266000   Apple
```

my shiny app:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Market Performance"),
  sidebarPanel('Things to put on the side',
               checkboxGroupInput("company", label = "Please choose a company...",
                           choices = list("Alibaba" = 'Alibaba',
                                          "Amazon" = 'Amazon',
                                          "Apple" = 'Apple',
                                          "Facebook" = 'Facebook',
                                          "Google" = 'Google',
                                          "Intel" = 'Intel',
                                          "Microsoft" = 'Microsoft',
                                          "SAP" = 'SAP'),
                           selected = 'Alibaba'),
               selectInput("type", label = "Please choose type of share...",
                           choices = list("Closing Price" = 'close_price ',
                                          "Share Volume" = ' volume'),
                           selected = 'close_price')),
  mainPanel('Main panel of the app',
            plotOutput('myplot')),
  position = 'left')


server <- function(input, output){
  output$myplot <- renderPlot(
    {
      req(input$type)
      data <- data_3 %>% filter(company %in% input$company)
      ggplot(data = data)+geom_line(aes_string(x = "date", y = input$type))
      
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Screenshot of the app doesn't run right when choosing more than one company[image]

Comment: Try adding `group = "company"` to your aesthetic here: `geom_line(aes_string(x = "date", y = input$type, group = "company"))`

Comment: oh it worked!!!! thank you so much!!